# How to get an infoWindow clicking on a Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events, infowindow

i would like to know how to open a info window when i click on a marker, i thought this was correct, but doesn't work.
This is the script

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            center: coords,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        placeMarker();
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            getComment(marker, infowindow);
      });
});
}
function getComment(marker, infowindow){
    var message = "Hello";
    infowindow.setContent(message);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
function placeMarker() {
    //place some marker
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: See the [documentation on infowindows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows).  I get `marker is undefined` with your code as posted (because it isn't defined). [Here is one example of how to make multiple markers with infowindows](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_markers_infowindows.html)

Answer (score 0):

Didn´t run it in jsfiddle, but the code below should be work.

You have to define `var marker` outside your function `placeMarker()`, like you did it with the `infoWindow`.

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            center: coords,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

        //position of marker = coords in this example
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: coords,
            map: map,
            title: "randomTitle",
            zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            getComment(marker, infowindow);
      });
});
}
function getComment(marker, infowindow){
    var message = "Hello";
    infowindow.setContent(message);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```